# PHP display two QR codes on same page

Tags: php, barcode

I am using this library to generate http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/ QR codes.

I am trying to display two barcodes on the same page using following linesl

```
    QRcode::png('My Name');
    QRcode::png($codeText);
```

My questions:

- Only one barcode is shown which is second one. No any error messages shown.
- Is it possible and normal to display the text under the QR code like I have seen in barcodes in case of it is not read by a reader for some reason, so the user still can read the text below the QR code?

Full code;

```
include('phpqrcode/qrlib.php');

//output image directly into browser, as PNG stream
QRcode::png('My Name');


//******************************************************************************************
$param = $_GET['id'];
//make sure script does not output anything!!! Otherwise it will break up PNG binary
ob_start("callback");

$codeText = 'New Fashion Shop '. $param;

$debugLog = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

QRcode::png($codeText);
//******************************************************************************************
```

Comment: The output of that library is the binary png data, not an html page. What you need is an html page with `<img>` tags, linking to a php page that outputs the image(s).

Comment: Did you got the fixed. I am also facing same issue.

Comment: @CalculatingMachine. yes. may i help u?

Comment: May i know how did you fixed it?

Comment: @CalculatingMachine. The page that above code generates code in binary format (not a typical html page). So another page, just use as: echo '<img src="pageofabovecode.php"/>';